# Jitter categorical variable and keep variable name in graph

Tags: r, jitter

I had to jitter points along a catagorical axis to avoid data overlay. Unfortunately, to do this, I needed to make my categorical variable a factor and then numerical. When I plot it, it remains numerical without the categorical labels. Is there a way I can get the labels to show up?

Here is the code:

```
levels(factor(All_VARs$Dataset))
[1] "Data1"        "Data2" "Data3"  

df$Dataset_jit <- jitter(as.numeric(factor(df$Dataset)))

ggplot(df, aes(x = POS_start, y = Dataset_jit, color = Type)) +
   geom_point() +
   scale_color_manual(values = annotation_color_associations) +
   theme_classic()
```

[image]

I would like the y axis to be categorical, while maintaining the jitter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position = position_jitter()`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = POS_start, y = as.factor(Set), color = as.factor(Type))) +
   geom_point(position = position_jitter(height = 0.2), show.legend = FALSE) +
   theme_classic() + 
   scale_color_manual(values = colorRampPalette(c("pink", "purple"))(5)) + 
   labs(x = "CDS Position", y = "Dataset")
```

[image]

**Edit**:
OP says they need to be able to do other things, so another approach is to manually control the y-axis with `scale_y_continuous`:

```
df$Dataset_jit <- jitter(as.numeric(factor(df$Set)))

ggplot(df, aes(x = POS_start, y = Dataset_jit, color = as.factor(Type))) +
   geom_point(show.legend = FALSE) +
   theme_classic() + 
   scale_color_manual(values = colorRampPalette(c("pink", "purple"))(5)) + 
   scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:3, labels = c("Data 1", "Data 2", "Data 3")) +
   labs(x = "CDS Position", y = "Dataset")
```

[image]

**Sample Data**

```
set.seed(3)
df <- data.frame(POS_start = round(runif(n = 100,1,1500),0),
                 Set = sample(1:3,100, prob = c(0.45,0.1,0.45), replace = TRUE),
                 Type = sample(1:5,100,replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually should have added that down the line I want to add segments that will be coming off of the points, so I will need the points to be jittered before plotting, as the segments will not line up with the points if I jitter the points separately

Comment: Thank you Ian, the second solution worked perfectly! I added the line:  `scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:3, labels = levels(df$Dataset)) + ` in case my dataset names change.